# Error "El archivo cargado excede la directiva upload_max_filesize en php.ini." al cargar tema en Wordpress alojado en Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, google-cloud-platform

Cómo puedo modificar el tamaño de máximo de carga en Google Cloud?

Comment: Conéctate por SSH y busca el archivo php.ini, luego busca esa directriz y modifícala, si nunca te has conectado por consola lo mejor es que busques información en otro lado, pues aunque no es un proceso muy complejo si es primera vez una guía visual te servirá mas, por ahora te invito a leer [ask] y hacer el [tour]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya gracias por tu observación, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @JefferzonBol Gracias por la guía, buscaré como conectarme por SSH.